# how to increase the rows and column dynamically using xslt 1.0 or 2.0?

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I need to create an excel document with the following xml:

```
<Information>  
  <Person>
     <Date>20131101</Date>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <Amount>1000</Amount>
  </Person>
  <Person>
     <Date>20131115</Date>
     <Name>Kelly</Name>
     <Amount>1000</Amount>
  </Person>
  <Person>
     <Date>20131101</Date>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <Amount>5000</Amount>
  </Person>
  <Person>
     <Date>20131101</Date>
     <Name>Anderson</Name>
     <Amount>500</Amount>
  </Person>
  <Person>
     <Date>20131103</Date>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <Amount>11000</Amount>
  </Person>
  <Person>
     <Date>20131115</Date>
     <Name>Anderson</Name>
     <Amount>10000</Amount>
   </Person>
```

And the Excel output should look like this:

```
          John   Kelly Anderson
20131101  6000   1000    500
20131103  11000   0      0
20131115   0      0     10000
```

Can this be done  totally dynamically by using xslt 1.0? as well as xslt 2.0 ?

Comment: In what way did you determine the order of your rows?

Comment: The answers are radically different for XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 - so I would suggest you make up your mind (if you can use a XSLT 2.0 processor, go for it and forget about XSLT 1.0). In any case, this is basically a grouping (or grouping within grouping) question, and there are are (at least) hundreds of previous questions on this topic that you could research.

Comment: Hi Kevin Brown: The order of the rows is in ascending order.

Comment: Michael: researched a lot of posts and couldn't find any that satisfied my issue. Could you help me in finding one? Would really appreciate that.